# Result type in structural refinement may not refer to a user-defined value class

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, compilation, structural-typing, value-class

When I define Wrapper as value class(extending AnyVal):

```
class Wrapper(val string: String) extends AnyVal

def wrapperHolder(w: Wrapper): {def wrapper: Wrapper} = new {
  def wrapper: Wrapper = w
}
```

I have following compile error for wrapperHolder:

```
Error:(5, 22) Result type in structural refinement may not refer to a user-defined value class
def wrapper: Wrapper = w
```

- Why it doesn't work for value class?

Comment: by the way. simplified version doesn't work too :     val f = new { def wrapper = new Wrapper("")}

Comment: I assume it's not allowed because value class is not actually a class from java/JVM perspective. it's primitive type with some static helpers generated on compilation stage.

Comment: In cases where the value class appears as an argument to a method, it won't work because refinement types often need to call the methods reflectively, and `Class.getMethod()` has no way to specify a Scala value class. However, this should not be an issue when it only appears as a result type. Perhaps the prohibition has the same origin, though, and Scala prohibits it more broadly than it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a trait may help:

```
class Wrapper(val string: String) extends AnyVal

trait WrapperHolder {
    def wrapper: Wrapper 
}

def wrapperHolder(w: Wrapper) : WrapperHolder = new WrapperHolder {
    def wrapper: Wrapper = w
}
```