# Value classes as structural type members

Tags: scala, structural-typing, value-class

Here is the simplified code:

```
class Value(val value: Int) extends AnyVal

val v = new Value(1)

val x = new { val f: Int = v.value }
println(x.f)

val y = new { val f: Value = v }
println(y.f)
```

Error: Result type in structural refinement may not refer to a user-defined value class

val y = new { val f: Value = v }

I don't understand. Since Int is also a value class, why Int can be used as member but my value class Value not? Why scala defines this limitation? How can I use user-defined value vlass in structural types?

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678323/result-type-in-structural-refinement-may-not-refer-to-a-user-defined-value-class

Comment: I would assume you imported  scala.language.reflectiveCalls for this to work (applies to line 4)

Comment: Why Int, Double can be used as structural type members?